# How to efficiently search a database table for all combinations of sub-strings in a piece of text?

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, optimization

So provided I have a MySQL table with hundreds of thousands of tags/keywords, and a user-supplied piece of text of arbitrary size, what is the most efficient way to extract all the keywords from this piece of text (keywords can be one or multiple words) that exist in the database table?

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm/strategy more than anything.

As an example, consider this random paragraph: "August 21st is the Great American Eclipse, the first Total Solar Eclipse to touch the US mainland since 1979 and the first since the creation of Reddit. We need your help to gather footage of how animals react to the eclipse, for science!  Learn how you can help in the comments."

Considering that "August", "Great American Eclipse", "Solar Eclipse", "US", "for science!" are all existing tags in the database table, I need a way to return all of them from the database efficiently.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Answer (score 1):

Fulltext indexing might be a common suggestion, but it isn't going to help in this case, because you're trying to find keywords in *input*, not in text that has already been indexed. You're doing the *opposite* of searching for one word among many indexed documents.

You can do the search this way:

```
SELECT t.tag
FROM tags AS t
WHERE ? LIKE CONCAT('%', t.tag, '%')
```

You will bind the paragraph of user input to the parameter placeholder `?`.

It'll be pretty slow. It'll probably take 10-30 seconds, depending on the horsepower of your server and other concurrent load on it.

But the good news is that you have to do this only once per input (if you save the results in a many-to-many table).